# Не работает библиотека ncurses-rs

Tags: rust, ncurses, libc

Здравствуйте! Искал ответ на свой вопрос про перехват нажатия клавиш и нашел [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs). Скомпилировал спомощью `Cargo`, дополнительно скачалось libc. Пытаюсь скомпилировать пример от автора (файл `ex_02.rs`):

```
/*
    Copyright © 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc
    See licensing in LICENSE file

    File: examples/ex_2.rs
    Author: Jesse 'Jeaye' Wilkerson
    Description:
      Basic input and attribute example.
*/

extern crate ncurses;

use std::char;
use ncurses::*;

fn main()
{
  /* Setup ncurses. */
  initscr();
  raw();

  /* Allow for extended keyboard (like F1). */
  keypad(stdscr, true);
  noecho();

  /* Prompt for a character. */
  printw("Enter a character: ");

  /* Wait for input. */
  let ch = getch();
  if ch == KEY_F1
  {
    /* Enable attributes and output message. */
    attron(A_BOLD() | A_BLINK());
    printw("\nF1");
    attroff(A_BOLD() | A_BLINK());
    printw(" pressed");
  }
  else
  {
    /* Enable attributes and output message. */
    printw("\nKey pressed: ");
    attron(A_BOLD() | A_BLINK());
    printw(format!("{}\n", char::from_u32(ch as u32).expect("Invalid char")).as_ref());
    attroff(A_BOLD() | A_BLINK());
  }

  /* Refresh, showing the previous message. */
  refresh();

  /* Wait for one more character before exiting. */
  getch();
  endwin();
}
```

Получаю однотипные ошибки - `unresolved name` к `getch, initsrc, raw` и другим функциям.
ОС - `Ubuntu 14.04`. `ncurses` есть. В папку с файлом ex_02.rs положил `libncures.rlib`. Компилирую так: `rustc -L. ex_02.rs`.
Попробовал скомпилировать с помощью `Cargo` в `Cargo.toml` добавил:

```
[dependencies]
ncurses = "*'
```

При сборке скачал и скомпилировал `ncurses` и `libc` без ошибок. При компиляции `daa` (имя проекта :)) пишет:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-m32" "-L" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/home/goopycs/projects/sad/target/debug/dda" "/home/goopycs/projects/sad/target/debug/dda.o" "-Wl,--whole-archive" "-lmorestack" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "/home/goopycs/projects/sad/target/debug/deps/libncurses-2ba8d0ae875390bf.rlib" "/home/goopycs/projects/sad/target/debug/deps/liblibc-38eabbf337f9ec62.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcollections-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunicode-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librand-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "-L" "/home/goopycs/projects/sad/target/debug" "-L" "/home/goopycs/projects/sad/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-L" "/home/goopycs/projects/sad/.rust/lib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu" "-L" "/home/goopycs/projects/sad/lib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu" "-Wl,--whole-archive" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lncursesw" "-lc" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lpthread" "-lrt" "-lgcc_s" "-lpthread" "-lc" "-lm" "-lcompiler-rt"
note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncursesw
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `dda`.
```

Comment: Мне на Fedora 22 понадобилось поставить `ncurses-devel`. В Ubuntu это, наверное, `libncursesw5-dev`.